# Java OOP-Accessing the last element in an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

I am practicing object orientation here entering in basketball player names and how many points scored and rebounds grabbed.

How would I go through each element in an array of objects to find the last player with an even amount of points?

This is the code I have so far to enter the information. What do I need to do in my second forloop to examine each element and then display the last element that fits my criteria?

```
class basketballObj
{
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        Basketball bbArray[];
        String theName;
        int thePoints;
        int theRebounds;
        int index;
        int noOfElements = 0;

        bbArray = new Basketball[3];

        for(index = 0; index < bbArray.length; index++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter a name ");
                theName = EasyIn.getString();
                System.out.println("Enter points scored ");
                thePoints = EasyIn.getInt();
                System.out.println("Enter rebounds grabbed ");
                theRebounds = EasyIn.getInt();
                bbArray[index] = new Basketball(theName, thePoints, theRebounds);
                noOfElements++; 
            }
        for(index = 0; index < bbArray.length; index++)
            {
                if(bbArray[index].getPoints() % 2 == 0)
                    {

                    }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if you want to find the last player with an even amount of points, you don't actually want to go through each element ;-). Try:

```
for(index = bbArray.length-1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            if(bbArray[index].getPoints() % 2 == 0)
                {
                   //add whatever relevant code here.
                   break; //this line breaks the for loop (because you've found a player with an even amount of score
                }
        }
```

we start at `bbArray.length-1` because while you array contains 3 elements, arrays are zero-indexed. Meaning that to get the first element, you will have to call `bbArray[0]`. Similarly call `bbArray[2]` for the last element.

Comment: You will want to start at `bbArray.length - 1` and have your condition be `index >= 0`

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Iterated your array backwards.

```
boolean found = false;
for(int index=array.length-1; index>-1 && !found; index--) {
    if(array[index].getPoints()%2 == 0) {
        // found element. Break out of for loop
        found=true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've pretty much got it.

Create a temporary, uninitialized variable `Basketball temp;` before the for loop that iterates through the `bbArray` and then set it equal to the `bbArray[index]` if the `if` condition is met.

If you want to save the index it was found at then create an `int indexFound;` as well.

Looping through it backwards as user2651804 suggested yields this:

```
public class basketballObj
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

    ...

        Basketball temp;
        int indexFound = -1;

    ...


        for(index = bbArray.length - 1; index >= 0; index++)
            {
                if(bbArray[index].getPoints() % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        temp = bbArray[index];
                        indexFound = index;
                        break;
                    }
            }


        //note temp will be null if no scores were even
        //if (temp != null)
        //you can use the above if statement if you don't want to use indexFound

        //you can also just check if indexFound == -1
        if (indexFound != -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Found at index: " + indexFound);
                //
            }
    }
}
```